# Best Practice to locally cache web service responses

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am populating an infinite list view with data from a webservice. The data is obtained as a response to POST requests made from the app. What is the best practice to cache such data so that a network call is not made every time the user just scrolls up and down the list?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) class, or better yet check out the [Android Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) framework developed by Google.

Comment: would you have any examples showing the usage of volley with cache. For example, how is cache size set. How do we force a request to not use the cache ?

Answer (score 0):

To do this in the past, I have added a cache scheme at network request layer to make the cache transparent to the API caller. The cache expires every x minutes. The cache is persisted using `SharedPreferences` so that it is available when the app restarts. For example, the API call might be:

`List<Item> items = server.getListItems(int page);`

Inside getListItems() you check the cache to see if there is a valid cache. If so you return the items in the cache, otherwise you make the network call.

Actually the API was a little more complicated because it supported returning an expired cache immediately, and then doing the network call and updating when the new results came back:

```
server.getListItems(int page, new ResultListener<List<Item>>() {
    public void onResult(List<Item> items) {
        ...
    }
});
```

In this scheme, when the cache expired onResult() would be called twice--once with the expired cache and once with the new results.

Good luck!

Comment: I line this idea. Could you please explain some more about your architecture and provide a little more pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

Try [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Another powerful library for image downloading and caching from square. 
It does everything about caching for you. But if you are still consisting of using LruCache, consider to allocate a special amount of memory for your app. Otherwise your app will cause memory hit.